# create json object

Tags: java, json

I want to store some offline data from a webpage.I am trying to use Json.i want to use this webpage in tablets and smart phone. Can any one help me in adding the jar

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.sun.
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Jsonnn {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", "asdf");
    obj.put("age", new Integer(100));

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.add("msg 1");
    list.add("msg 2");
    list.add("msg 3");

    obj.put("messages", list);

    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\test.json");
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(obj);

     }

}
```

Comment: you want to add the JAR's to your library ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you want to do with the jar? Which jar?

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONObject; how to import this....i want the link of the jar which contains this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for the JAR's you can download them from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) or [another one here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/net.sf.json-lib/jars/json-lib-0.9.jar.html?all=true) and input it into your library